# HDD feels like baby kicking - normal?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb

Got a new 3.5 inch HDD put in external enclosure. Is it normal to feel like a baby kicking if you rest your hand on the HDD while it is running? Happens constantly like twice a second but randomly. I have no idea as i've only ever had internal HDD before... just hope it is normal.

Comment: This is not normal.  This means your hdd is not secure enough.  You should be able to feel the HDD working, just like say a disk in your optical drive, but thats about it.

Answer (score 0):

That will be the kickback from the heads moving across the disk. It's not normally very strong.

You'll also notice a strong "precession" effect if you turn it around in your hands.

Comment: its not strong, but easy to feel... i hope it is just normal operation of the heads. It's a 2TB drive so i guess it might have up to 4 heads in there moving around.